# Sincronizar carpetas automáticamente con Filezilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Estoy intentando montar un servidor **FTP** con **Filezila** para realizar una sincronización automática de los archivos al momento de establecer la conexión. He logrado habilitar la comparación de las carpetas pero no logre realizar la copia de forma automáticamente.

Adjunto una captura del cliente Filezilla

[image: Captura de pantalla cliente Filezilla]

Comment: si mi respuesta e ha sido de utilidad puedes marcarla como mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No logre establecer con **Filezilla** una sincronnizacion confiable pero encontre otro programa que premite la sincronizacion de documentos por FTP.

Adjunto una captura y el link de la pagina.

[FullSync](https://fullsync.sourceforge.io/index.php)

[image: Captura de conexion FullSync]
[image: Captura de app FullSync]

Answer (score 3):

Encontré estos pasos en internet ojala te sea de utilidad.

1. Copie el nombre de la carpeta, luego haz clic en "Desconectar" en la barra de herramientas y cierra FileZilla.
2. Cree una carpeta con el mismo nombre de la carpeta a sincronizar en el disco "C: \"
3. Inicie FileZilla de nuevo. Haga clic en "Archivo" y "Administrador del sitio", a continuación, seleccione su servidor FTP de la lista. Haga clic en la pestaña "Avanzado" en la ventana del Administrador del sitio y, a continuación, haga clic en el botón "Examinar" situado junto al campo "Directorio local predeterminado". Vaya a la nueva carpeta que creó en el Explorador de Windows y, a continuación, haga clic en "Abrir".
4. Asegúrese de que el nombre de la carpeta en el campo "Default Remote Directory" coincide exactamente con el del campo "Default Local Directory". Sin embargo, si los nombres de las carpetas no coinciden, simplemente escriba el nombre de la carpeta del campo "Default Local Directory" (sin el "C: \") en el campo "Default Remote Directory".
5. Haga clic y active la opción "Utilizar exploración sincronizada" en la ficha Avanzar y, a continuación, haga clic en el botón "Conectar". Después de conectar y establecer una sesión FTP con el servidor, FileZilla le pide que sincronice las carpetas. Haga clic en el botón "Sí" para descargar archivos del servidor a la nueva carpeta que creó en el disco duro de su computadora local. Después de realizar la sincronización inicial de las carpetas, FileZilla analiza los cambios cada vez que se vuelve a conectar al servidor FTP. Si existen nuevos archivos en cualquier carpeta, local o remota, la aplicación le pedirá que sincronice los directorios. Si hace clic en "Sí", FileZilla carga o descarga archivos para sincronizar las carpetas según sea necesario.

Para mas información puedes ir al [post](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/synchronize-filezilla-47982.html) original.